# Python: Splitting composite words to known words (from dictionary)

Tags: python

I need a very efficient algorithm to do the following:

I have to separate composite words in any language. English for example.

But there is a problem occurring when a word is composed of two words that are sharing the last and the first letter.

I.e. the first word ends with the letter in which the second begins.

So, we have a dictionary containing all possible words, make it short:

Let say we want to split the word 'lightshow' with this exemplary dict:

```
d = {"light": "Noun, S, N",
    "lights": "Noun, P, N",
    "how": "Q",
    "show": "Noun, S, N",
    ...}
```

My algorithm now splits the word in chunks into two lists:

```
left = []; right = []
for x in range(len(word)-1, 1, -1):
    ls = word[:x]; rs = word[x:]
    if ls.lower() in d: left.append(ls)
    if rs.lower() in d: right.append(rs)
```

Then I find the longest word in left and the longest word in right list.

So, I know of which words the word consists and where they begin and end inside the composite word.

Don't worry now about overkill cases where word is not in dict, and words doesn't match etc., I just want to present the idea to you and my biggest problem with this approach.

Using this approach at the end of whole algorithm the result will be:

```
["lights", "how"]
```

instead of:

```
["light", "show"]
```

what is, as you can imagine unacceptable.

Oh, yes I can check whether in dict exists a word show by using the:

```
l = ["lights", "how"]
if l[0][-1]+l[1] in d: <repair the list>
```

but it is inpractical, also my algorithm deals recursively with words that are composed of more than 2 words.

It also deals with words that are separated with differences in capitalization etc.

That is why I didn't post it whole because it is big and optimized so it would be a lot of unimportant code to read.

Oh, yes, I can do some improvements with making the last word primary. Or comparing the lengths when choosing which one goes first etc.

But it is not always possible to decide correctly with these manipulations. For example, what to do with found longest words that intersect in more than one letter?

I want to do it all within one loop. Speed is imperative.

Note: dictionary I supplied is exemplary. The dataset I have to work with doesn't contain any information about the type of word. Just its pronunciation from which only useful info can be whether the word is short/long when spoken.

Hope to see some very good ideas here. Remember, code has to be very efficient. It is used in real time by a TTS to pronounce words that aren't in dictionary but actually contain words that are, and usually pronunciation matches.
No need for providing me with code, just ideas to put to action.

Answer (score 3):

You could favour the syllable breaks within the word that are suggested by a hyphenation algorithm or dictionary in these cases. A good hyphenation algorithm will tell you that `light-show` and `data-set` break up the word correctly.

I don't think it is possible to get this right in absolutely every case though, without have a data file somewhere that explicitly maps `lightshow` to `light + show` and `dataset` to `data + set`, etc. Whatever algorithm you come up with will always have exceptions where it makes mistakes.

Frank Liang's hyphenation algorithm [is available here for Python](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/hyphenate.html), and helps with one of your two examples:

```
>>> hyphenate_word("dataset")
['dataset']
>>> hyphenate_word("lightshow")
['light', 'show']
```

You could try testing combinations of the syllables returned by `hyphenate_word()` (which should be pretty efficient, as it is used within TeX), and if it doesn't find anything try your original approach.

It does quite well on these:

```
 [hyphenate_word(x) for x in ["backwoodsman", "whatsoever", "hereupon", "counterclockwise", "notwithstanding", "highwayman "]]
[['back', 'woods', 'man'], ['what', 'so', 'ev', 'er'], ['here', 'upon'], ['coun', 'ter', 'clock', 'wise'], ['notwith', 'stand', 'ing'], ['high', 'way', 'man ']]
```

[A handy list of compound words](http://www.manythings.org/vocabulary/lists/a/words.php?f=compound_words), and also some [triple compound words](http://lawsofsilence.blogspot.ca/2010/07/english-closed-triple-compound-words.html).

Comment: Wow, cool! I'll probably use portions of the algo you suggested. Although there is a drawback of having one extra dictionary in memory along with the pronunciation one. And no more or less but in the tree of dictionaries form. I am looking at the code and asking myself whether this is efficient or not. I should test it for speed. I think some optimization should be done.

Comment: BTW, I tested my splitting algorithm against lists you provided. And, mostly because I have an extensive dictionary that contains most of compounds, splitting wasn't needed, but when it was it was mostly OK. On normal compounds troubles were with grasshopper: grass hopper, but then I am not myself sure whether a word grass shopper has any sense. :D While grass hopper has some. :D In triple compounds words from superman group were troubling. So I cannot say that my algo doesn't work, but when a case like lightshow pops up I am mad. Especially if it repeats through the text.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 factors that come to my mind instantly, however you might want to validate it with your dataset first.

1. Weight by word type. Often composed words will consist of nouns, so if you have the choice between `N + Q` and `N + N`, it is likely that `N + N` is the correct solution. From the top of my head I cannot think of an example you would prefer something over a noun, but that's the point that you should probably check
2. Weight by Singular, Plural. Especially for "s" in the middle it will often be a case of a plural s, so prefer `S + X` over `P + X`

Comment: There is one big problem, my real dataset doesn't contain information about a word. Just its pronunciation. I am sorry I forgot to mention this, I'll edit my Q now. BTW, dataset is one of the words incorrectly splitted ["datas", "et"] :D

Comment: too bad. But then you might at least capture the `s` problems by choosing the combination where the `s` is at the beginning of the second word rather than the end of the first one.

Comment: The problem is, there is not only S, there is d (like in replacedict), and other letters too, especially with usermade words and typos.

Comment: My idea is not to use longest word but have two longest existing words at least from the left side of composite, and then use the shorter one. But how to achieve this efficiently without sorting is a Q at this moment for me, because I am having a temporary brain freeze just now. I mean, some modified max() will do. I'll have to try this after unfreezing takes place.

Comment: That sounds like you always want to choose the shorter "left" word. As in your lightship example. Does that mean there is never the possibility that the correct result would be the longer word?

Comment: There is a possibility. I just remembered to explain that in current situation I always get 2 words. I can see whether they overlap only by throwing them at the dict once again with modifications. Something have to be done while choosing the longest one. For speed and practical reasons. I mean with one letter is OK, but what when overlap is bigger like in English participles? Perhaps there is such rare true composite, but typo is always possible.